# Timer stops after a few minutes, why is that?

Tags: .net, vb.net, timer

I have a timer which checks every 5 minutes a web page for changes through a Webbrowser Element. Whenever the page changes (on a new order), my Timer will play a .wav file (beep). This seems to work the first few minutes or sometimes the first few hours, but then it will stop checking without a warning/exception.

What could cause this problem?

Edit #1

Here the Code I'm using:

```vb
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    Dim sQuelltext As String = WebBrowser1.DocumentText.ToString
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sQuelltext) And sQuelltext.Contains("pending") Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(soundFile, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you share a code?

Comment: sure! I just edited my previous post, since I don't know how to paste in Code into comments.

Comment: If nothing is disabling the timer, I would suggest for you to debug  this by adding an `ELSE` statement and playing a different Audio tune. Or add some kind of file logging every time Timer is triggered. File logging is better, because you don't have to sit and wait to hear timer triggering. Timer shouldn't disable itself, even if a runtime error triggers inside of the Tick event.

Comment: IF you are sure that no other code may stop the timer, then maybe the object WebBrowser1.DocumentText returns nothing, so you get an exception, leading to **Not** playing the audio file. If you run the program in Debug mode, maybe you like to activate in menu "Debug" -> Exceptions  and check the "Thrown" for all exceptions. This makes sure that execution is stopped whenever an exception occurs, even if handled. Maybe this can help. Also maybe add a previous line to check **If WebBrowser1 Is Nothing Then...** to avoid an exception there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usualy a timer does not stop without reason.

Typical problem may be: to avoid a running of the timer while the last call is still not complete (avoiding unexpected racing problems), in the first line of timer_tick  the timer is disabled and at the very end timer is enabled again.

Now it was forgotten that at a few locations a return statement is used, or some code lines may trigger an exception. In that case re-enabling the timer will not be executed, and it seemed to stop

**Update**
 If WebBrowser1 is Nothing/Disposed, then accessing it may lead to an exception. If that happens, then you may interpret 'no audio' aas feedback that timer has stopped, while it actually triggers, but only the code lines are executed, that do not create an exception (and then the method will just be left). Happens very seldom, is strange behavior, but this may be a case.

So you can add on the very first line of the timer something to toggle the state of an object, and at the bottom of it another toggle of a second object.

If nothing changes then something is wrong, if only first toggle happens, then set a breakpoint there and follow the next lines. If step-by-step debugging seems to jump out from one specific line, then there is something wrong. You can use immediate window to check the contents of parts of the next line. Usually it is very easy to fix , as soon as you found the cause for the error